# Запуск функции из другого контроллера

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Всем привет!

Не получается решить такую задачу.

Есть два контроллера - ProfileController и NotifyController.

notifyController View:

```
<div ng-controller="notifyController" ng-init="getMsg()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in myMsg.group">
            <a href="#" ng-click="getMsg(item.id)">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="item in myMsg.msg">
        {{item.text}}
    </div>
</div>
```

profileController View:

```
<div ng-controller="profileController">
    <button ng-click="getMsg(44)">Написать</button>
</div>
```

Задача стоит такая: нажав на кнопку "Написать", сервис pmService подгружал в контроллер notify новые данные и отображал их там.

```
 app.factory('pmService', function ($http) {

    return {
        privateMessages: {
            loader: false,
            group: {},
            data: {}
        },
        getMsg: function getMsg(id) {
                $http.post('/pm/read/' + id, {
                    readed: privateMessages.loader,
                    added: privateMessages.data.length > 0
                }).success(function (data) {
                    privateMessages.data = data.msg;
                    privateMessages.group = data.group;
                });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('profileController',function(pmService){
    $scope.getMsg = function(id){
        pmService.getMsg(id);
    };
});

app.controller('notifyController',function(pmService){
    $scope.myMsg = '';
    $scope.getMsg = function(id){
         pmService.getMsg(id);
         $scope.myMsg = pmService.privateMessages();
    };
});
```

Первая проблема - почему-то не отправляется ajax-запрос, вторая - не присваиваются данные myMsg и не отображаются. Третья проблема - не понимаю, что должна делать функция в profileController, чтобы обновлять данные в контроллере notifyController.

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую!
Сразу с ходу: это нормально работает?

```
$scope.myMsg = pmService.privateMessages();
```

Вызов объекта вроде как...  Может, из-за этого ваш третий вопрос?

По второй проблеме - посмотрите на контекст выполнения функции getMsg в фабрике. Может быть, лучше оформить сервис как сервис, а не как фабрику? Тогда контексты выполнения будут более ясны. Например, вот так:

```
app.service('pmService', function($http) {
    var self = this; // для удобства разруливания котнекстов
    self.privateMessages = {...};
    self.getMsg = function(...){...; self.privateMessages = ...};
});
```

В profileController у вас все нормально, она вызывает метод сервиса, сервис отрабатывает, меняет данные внутри себя, а notifyController эти данные подхватывает и рисует.